# How to split mysql table into 2 tables and keep reference

Tags: mysql

I'm in a middle of a DB migration, and I have to split a MySql table into two tables, and keep reference between them.

i.e. :

```
ORIGINAL_TABLE
    ORIGINAL_TABLE_ID
    DATE
    TOTAL
```

into

```
TABLE_1
    ID
    DATE

TABLE_2
    ID
    TOTAL
    TABLE_1_ID
```

This is just an example to explain what I want to do, how can I split ORIGINAL TABLE and keep reference between the 2 tables that are generated?

Comment: How are you going to run the migration? Directly in MySQL? or with any scripting language?

Comment: at first glance it doesn't look as if you need to do this. Please add more information

Comment: I'm ussing Pentaho Kettle tool, but since it's kind of complicated to use it to do this, i'm searching how to do it with mysql directly. I need to do this migration, since we have normalize some tables, and designed them properly. This is just an example of what i'm looking for